# How to show a modal pop up above other modal pop up

Tags: jquery, html

I have a Modal Pop up . When I click on a button in the Modal Pop Up, another Modal Pop Up shows up. But some of the second modal pop up it hides behind the first modal pop up. How to make it show above the first modal pop up.

Any ideas and suggestions are appreciated !

Comment: Post some code pls. We have no idea what you are doing. Secondly, a modal popup over another modal popup is generally a bad idea from a usability perspective.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting the **z-index** of the popup wrapper you want above greater than the other..

```
#popup1 {
   z-index: 9997;
}

#popup2 {
   z-index: 9998; // This will come above popup1
}
```

This is provided that `#popup1` and `#popup2` have the same parent.

Answer (score 2):

set the z-index of popup which should be on the top, highest than any other element on the DOM. Think of it as the layer which should be on the top.

Answer (score 2):

You could solve this dynamically by using with the use of two classes and jQuery:

```
.PopUp {
    z-index:999;
    }

.PopUp-focus {
    z-index:1000;
    }
```

All popups, by default, would have the class 'PopUp'.

Then create the following jQuery function to handle the event of opening an popup. (This may be out of context, as you've provided no code, but for the sake of example...)

```
function OpenPopup(popupID) {

    $(".PopUp-focus").removeClass('PopUp-focus').addClass('PopUp');

    $("#"+popupID+"").removeClass('PopUp').addClass('PopUp-focus');

    $("#"+popupID+"").fadeIn(500); // Your code to make the popup appear. (Random example).

}
```

--

```
<div onClick="OpenPopup('ID of popup');">Open Popup</div>
```

This will very simply solve the problem with two popups being open simultaneously by giving the popup that has most recently been opened a higher z-index than any other.

The drawback being if the situations were to arise where you had more than 2 popups open, the background popups would be at risk of clashing and a more elaborate script would be needed to decrement/increment z-indexs. But it depends on the nature and scope of your project.