# Perform second popup via first popup page in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, popup

I have planed to implement two pops in asp.net page. The First popup perform when the page button Click, and the Second popup perform when the first popup button click.

But When I Implement this in code, i got fist popup only. Can't got the second popup open.

[image]

**ASPX Code-**

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .Background
        {
            background-color: Black;
            filter: alpha(opacity=90);
            opacity: 0.8;
        }
        .Popup
        {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            border-width: 3px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: black;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            width: 400px;
            height: 350px;
        }
        .lbl
        {
            font-size: 16px;
            font-style: italic;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowModalPopup() {
            $find("mp1").show();
            return false;
        }
        function HideModalPopup() {
            // alert("Yes");
            $find("mp1").hide();
            return false;
        }
        function ShowModalPopup1() {
            $find("ModalPopupExtender1").show();
            return false;
        }
        function HideModalPopup1() {
            // alert("Yes");
            $find("ModalPopupExtender1").hide();
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Button ID="btnPopup1" runat="server" Text="Fill Form in Popup" />
    <!-- ModalPopupExtender -->
    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panl1" TargetControlID="btnPopup1"
        BehaviorID="modalPopupBehavior" CancelControlID="btnHide" BackgroundCssClass="Background">
    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panl1" runat="server" CssClass="Popup" align="center" Style="display: none">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" />
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" Text="RED" runat="server" ForeColor="red" />
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" TextAlign="Left" Text="ssdd" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnPopup1" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:Button ID="btnHide" runat="server" Text="Hide Modal Popup" OnClientClick="return HideModalPopup()" />

                <!-- ModalPopupExtender 2 -->
                <asp:Button ID="btnPopup2" runat="server" Text="Fill Form in Popup" />
                <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel1"
                    TargetControlID="btnPopup2" BehaviorID="modalPopupBehavior" CancelControlID="btnHide1"
                    BackgroundCssClass="Background">
                </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="Popup" align="center" Style="display: none">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="Blue" runat="server" ForeColor="Blue" />
                            <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" TextAlign="Left" Text="ssdd" runat="server" />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnPopup2" EventName="Click" />
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnHide1" runat="server" Text="Hide Modal Popup" OnClientClick="return HideModalPopup1()" />
                </asp:Panel>
                <!-- ModalPopupExtender 2 -->
    </asp:Panel>
    <!-- ModalPopupExtender -->
    </form>
</body>
```

**C# Code -**

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label2.Text = "Blue";
}

protected void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link might be of good use to you.

http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com.au/2009/03/how-to-open-modalpopup-inside.html

Also to have a modal pop up over another modal popup you need to set the `z-index` otherwise there are chances that the 2nd popup might hide behind the 1st. The following are the links which explains the same.

[How to show a modal pop up above other modal pop up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786343/how-to-show-a-modal-pop-up-above-other-modal-pop-up)
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codejunkie/archive/2009/06/23/multiple-modal-popups-and-z-index.aspx
http://tiredblogger.wordpress.com/2008/07/24/layering-modal-popups-using-css-z-index/
http://forums.asp.net/p/1280547/2458840.aspx#2458840

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look on below url.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/546817/ASP-NET-Popup-Control-Displaying-as-multiple-neste

[image]